# Calculate type II error

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

How can I calculate the theoretical type II error in this particular case using R?

```
a <- rnorm(500, 10, 5)
b <- rnorm(500, 10, 5)
t.test(a, b)
```

Comment: The two variables have the same mean. The theoretical type-II error rate in this case is 0.

Comment: ... or undefined ... you might be looking for `power.t.test(n=500,delta=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Type 2 error is the probability of failing to reject the null when the null is indeed false. In this case both variables a and b have the same mean 10. So, the null is not false. Therefore, there is no question of type II error here.